# Spring boot WebFlux and Angular: How to consume and render from a reactive api?

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I am new to reactive programming and trying to build a simple angular application with spring boot backend api. I have userinfo table in postgre with 100k sample users. I want my angular app display the table reactively. If new user is added it should display as it comes. Also table should be displayed as data comes not when the request is completed. I am not sure where I am doing the mistake. The table is populated only when the result is completed. And also the new user is not added to the table. So its not reactive I guess.

Here is my table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS userinfo (
    userId INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('userid_seq') PRIMARY KEY ,
    firstName TEXT NOT NULL,
    lastName TEXT NOT NULL,
    email TEXT NOT NULL,
    phone VARCHAR(10) NULL, 
    address1 VARCHAR(100) NULL,     
    address2 VARCHAR(100) NULL,     
    city VARCHAR(100) NULL,     
    state VARCHAR(100) NULL,    
    country VARCHAR(100) NULL,      
    zip VARCHAR(100) NULL
);
```

And I have spring boot reactive rest api with below dependencies(from build.gradle).

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:r2dbc-postgresql'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
}
```

UserInfo model class:

```
@Table(name = "userinfo")
public class UserInfo { 
    @Id
    @Column("userId")
    private Long userId;
    @Column("firstName")
    private String firstName;
    @Column("lastName")
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String phone;
    private String password;
    private String address1;
    private String address2;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String country;
    private String zip;
    
    //Getters & Setters
     
}
```

my repository class:

```
public interface UserInfoRepository extends R2dbcRepository<UserInfo, Long>{
    Mono<UserInfo> findByEmail(String email);
    Mono<UserInfo> findByUserId(Long userId);
}
```

my service class:

```
@Service
public class UserInfoService {
    @Autowired
    private UserInfoRepository repo;
    
    public Flux<UserInfo> getAll() {
        return repo.findAll();
    }
}
```

controller class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/userinfo")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public class WebController {
    public static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebController.class);
    @Autowired
    private UserInfoService userInfoService;
    
    @GetMapping("/users")
    public Flux<UserInfo> getAll() {
        return userInfoService.getAll();
    }
}
```

**Angular App**

my service:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { UserInfo } from '../model/userinfo';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpServiceService {
  private baseUrl = "http://localhost:9095/api/userinfo";

  private headers= new HttpHeaders()
    .set('content-type', 'application/json')
    .set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getUsers(): Observable<UserInfo[]> {
    return this.http.get<UserInfo[]>(
      this.baseUrl + '/users', {'headers':this.headers});
  }
}
```

My component class where I want to display users reactively.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserInfo } from 'src/app/model/userinfo';
import { HttpServiceService } from 'src/app/services/http-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  count: any;
  service: HttpServiceService;
  usersList: Array<UserInfo> | undefined;

  constructor(service: HttpServiceService) {
    this.service = service;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.service.getUsers().subscribe({
      next: (result: any) => {
        this.count = result.length;
        // this.usersList?.push(result);
        this.usersList = result;
      },
      error: (err: any) => {
        console.log(err);
      },
      complete: () => {
        console.log('complete');
      }
    });
  }
}
```

the template:

```
<div CLASS="card container mt-3 p-3">
  <div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">
      Total Users: <span class="badge badge-light">{{count}}</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <table class="table">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">User ID</th>
          <th scope="col">Name</th>
          <th scope="col">City</th>
          <th scope="col">Email</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of usersList">
          <th scope="row">{{ item.userId }}</th>
          <td>{{item.firstName}} {{item.lastName}}</td>
          <td>{{item.city}}</td>
          <td>{{item.email}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you found your solution? If so. please share us

Comment: unfortunately I could not find a solution. Will definitely share if I did

Answer (score 0):

You could try: "application/stream+json" or "text/event-stream" as "content-type" in the header in HttpServiceService